# Unsure How to Update ChromeDriver for a TypeScript Selenium Project

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ts-jest

After running a typescript Selenium test file, I get the following error:

"SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 90.0.4430.212 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Following is a screenshot of the error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAsnH.png)

I know I need to update my chromedriver version. Ideally, I'd like to use WebdriverManager or a similar tool, but I have not found a way to use that tool for TypeScript/Node/Jest projects. I can simply download the new version of chromedriver, but I will need to update it in my package-lock.json file, shown here:

"chromedriver": {
"version": "87.0.7",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chromedriver/-/chromedriver-87.0.7.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-7J7iN2rJuSDsKb9BUUMewJt07PuTlZYd809D10dUCT1rjMD3i2jUw7dum9RxdC1xO3aFwMd8TwZ5NR82T+S+Dg==",
"requires": {
"@testim/chrome-version": "^1.0.7",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"del": "^6.0.0",
"extract-zip": "^2.0.1",
"https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
"mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
"proxy-from-env": "^1.1.0",
"tcp-port-used": "^1.0.1"
}

(Below is a screenshot):

[Package-lock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWWKC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using npm, you just need to run:

```
npm install chromedriver
npm install chromedriver --save-dev #if you need it as a dev dependency
npm install
```

This should update your package.json and package-lock.json files with the necessary package versions.